# Как упростить функцию с двумя циклами или лучше оставить как есть?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

У меня есть две почти одинаковые функции где два цикла одинаковые, но код внутри разный, как мне сделать более правильно
Оставить так же как есть или изменить обе функции до одной или как вы делаете когда сталкиваетесь с таким кодом, просто интересно какой метод вы считаете правильным.

```
        template <class T1>
        void function_A(T1 & array_test) {
            for (int h = 0; h < 3; ++h) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {

                    // КОД 1
                }
            }
        }

        template <class T1>
        void function_B(T1 & array_test) {
            for (int h = 0; h < 3; ++h) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {

                    // КОД 2
                }
            }
        }
```

Сейчас так, зависит от условия выполнить одну или другую функцию

```
    if (functiontest == 0) {
        function_A(array_test);
    }
    if (functiontest == 1) {
        function_B(array_test);
    }
```

Я думаю сделать так, но не уверен что это лучше чем верхний вариант, зато внутри функции будет только код без циклов, но и передавать нужно будет три аргумента а не один

```
    for (int h = 0; h < 3; ++h) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {

            if (functiontest == 0) {
                function_A(h, i, array_test);
            }
            if (functiontest == 1) {
                function_B(h, i, array_test);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код можно записать в виде некоторой функции? Тогда можно сделать так:

```
template <class T1, class Func>
void function(T1 & array_test, Func f) {
    for (int h = 0; h < 3; ++h) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {

            f(.......);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Типа сделать еще одну функцию поверх функций?

Comment: Я об этом тоже думал, но потом подумал что много функций тоже не очень хорошо, нужно будет смотреть с одной функции к другой, у меня эти циклы очень часто в коде встречаются я поэтому и хочу узнать как вы обычно делаете.

Comment: Вот вам и привели пример, другого не дано. Либо вы используете switch, либо пробрасываете адрес функции, которую будете вызывать внутри цикла. Ничего страшного не случится, если у вас будет функций N+1, где N - это количество вариантов кода, который будет в цикле и 1 - это функция-обертка для всех остальных

Comment: Обычно? Без всяких шаблонов :) — конечно, если не для 5-10 разных типов это приходится делать... А если для одного — так шаблон и ни к чему...

Comment: Отмечу пока как ответ, раз других вариантов нет )

Comment: Как репер рифму зачитал

Comment: :) Есть такое...